# Iterate through nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django-rest-framework

Using Edmunds API (edmunds.mashery.io), I am trying to parse a car object.
As you can see the JSON Response is well formatted into the following nested tree:
Make (id, name, models) --> Models (id, name, nicename, styles) --> Styles

With this in mind, consider the following API response:

```
{
"name": "BMW",
"model": [
    {
        "id": "BMW_2_Series",
        "name": "2 Series",
        "nicename": "2-series",
        "styles": [
            {
                "id": 200744428,
                "name": "228i 2dr Coupe (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 6M)",
                "drivenwheels": "rear wheel drive",
                "numofdoors": 2,
                "manufacturercode": "162A",
                "engine": 200744477,
                "transmission": 200744479,
                "trim": "228i",
                "pricebasemsrp": "32850.0",
                "pricebaseinvoice": "30720.0",
                "pricedeliverycharges": "995.0",
                "submodelbody": "Coupe",
                "submodelname": "2 Series Coupe",
                "submodelnicename": "coupe",
                "mpghighway": "34",
                "mpgcity": "22",
                "categoriesmarket": "Luxury,Performance",
                "epaclass": "Subcompact Cars",
                "vehiclesize": "Compact",
                "crossover": "NA",
                "primarybodytype": "Car"
            },
            {
                "id": 200744429,
                "name": "228i SULEV 2dr Coupe (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 8A)",
                "drivenwheels": "rear wheel drive",
                "numofdoors": 2,
                "manufacturercode": "162B",
                "engine": 200744475,
                "transmission": 200744478,
                "trim": "228i SULEV",
                "pricebasemsrp": "32850.0",
                "pricebaseinvoice": "30720.0",
                "pricedeliverycharges": "995.0",
                "submodelbody": "Coupe",
                "submodelname": "2 Series Coupe",
                "submodelnicename": "coupe",
                "mpghighway": "35",
                "mpgcity": "23",
                "categoriesmarket": "Luxury,Performance",
                "epaclass": "Subcompact Cars",
                "vehiclesize": "Compact",
                "crossover": "NA",
                "primarybodytype": "Car"
            }]},
    {
        "id": "BMW_3_Series",
        "name": "3 Series",
        "nicename": "3-series",
        "styles": [
            {
                "id": 200729833,
                "name": "320i 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 8A)",
                "drivenwheels": "rear wheel drive",
                "numofdoors": 4,
                "manufacturercode": "16TI",
                "engine": 200741606,
                "transmission": 200741614,
                "trim": "320i",
                "pricebasemsrp": "33150.0",
                "pricebaseinvoice": "31000.0",
                "pricedeliverycharges": "995.0",
                "submodelbody": "Sedan",
                "submodelname": "3 Series Sedan",
                "submodelnicename": "sedan",
                "mpghighway": "36",
                "mpgcity": "24",
                "categoriesmarket": "Luxury",
                "epaclass": "Compact Cars",
                "vehiclesize": "Midsize",
                "crossover": "NA",
                "primarybodytype": "Car"
            }
       }
}
```

Using JQuery's ajax, I am able to load the JSON response. I am trying to create dynamic buttons based on the Model's id (Each model is a boxed container containing information about the model populated from this response.

My current issue stands that when I try to iterate JQuery's .each, I get:
key: model
value: [Object] [Object] ... [Object]

What I'm trying to accomplish is accessing the Object's content in a dynamic way and populate to populate it.

In addition to the scope of this question, I have a more general question based on the BIG Picture:

Using Edmund's API I plan on making a car selection website using buttons where:
State 1: Makes populated, when make is selected, go to state 2.
State 2: Model buttons are populated from JSON API, move to state 3.

Here is my current jQuery function:

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/makes/200000081.json', function( models ) {
      console.log(models.model[0].name)

  });
```

Here is my output:

> 2 Series

If I change model[0] to model[3] the result changes (as it should.)
How can I get model[x].name in an array I can manipulate with HTML?

Comment: `is JQuery a viable option for creating a dynamic SPA` - jQuery isn't an architecture. It's a toolbelt for working with the DOM. Yes, you can absolutely built `SPA`'s with jQuery in your toolbelt, the same way you can build them with vanilla JS. If you rely on `jQuery` to provide the architecture for your application (meaning you rely on your application state to be persisted, basically in the DOM), then you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @Adam Thank you for answering the big picture. So to follow up, what would be your recommendation for such an approach in order to opt in for a world of pleasure?

Comment: Experience. Or failing that, probably using a framework that enforces good architecture by default, like angular, or React/Redux (React alone is not enough). Using frameworks like these makes the learning curve steeper, but it comes with the added benefit of teaching you good architectural principles without you even realizing you're learning them.... It really depends on the complexity level of your SPA. If it's pretty light (with no plans on evolving to something heavier), then your needs for good architecture diminish and the frameworks just add a time cost.

Comment: If you're looking for a dynamic single page application, I'd highly suggest React. It is a frontend framework created by Facebook to easily manage the state of your application. The docs are [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/)

Comment: @Adam, I have already setup Django with DRF in order to approach such frameworks. While I agree that frameworks offer architecture and good practice. Which framework do you believe would be easy to integrate with this setup? (I was suggested to use Meteor, Aureilia, as well as Angular, React/Redux)

Comment: Personal preference question, ask 7 different people and they'll tell you 7 different frameworks (all because they are used to them). React/Redux seems to be held in pretty high regard nowadays, but feel free to explore. **There is no right answer about which frontend framework to use**, don't let anybody tell you otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could help.

```js
var response = {
"name": "BMW",
"model": [
    {
        "id": "BMW_2_Series",
        "name": "2 Series",
        "nicename": "2-series",
        "styles": [
            {
                "id": 200744428,
                "name": "228i 2dr Coupe (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 6M)",
                "drivenwheels": "rear wheel drive",
                "numofdoors": 2,
                "manufacturercode": "162A",
                "engine": 200744477,
                "transmission": 200744479,
                "trim": "228i",
                "pricebasemsrp": "32850.0",
                "pricebaseinvoice": "30720.0",
                "pricedeliverycharges": "995.0",
                "submodelbody": "Coupe",
                "submodelname": "2 Series Coupe",
                "submodelnicename": "coupe",
                "mpghighway": "34",
                "mpgcity": "22",
                "categoriesmarket": "Luxury,Performance",
                "epaclass": "Subcompact Cars",
                "vehiclesize": "Compact",
                "crossover": "NA",
                "primarybodytype": "Car"
            },
            {
                "id": 200744429,
                "name": "228i SULEV 2dr Coupe (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 8A)",
                "drivenwheels": "rear wheel drive",
                "numofdoors": 2,
                "manufacturercode": "162B",
                "engine": 200744475,
                "transmission": 200744478,
                "trim": "228i SULEV",
                "pricebasemsrp": "32850.0",
                "pricebaseinvoice": "30720.0",
                "pricedeliverycharges": "995.0",
                "submodelbody": "Coupe",
                "submodelname": "2 Series Coupe",
                "submodelnicename": "coupe",
                "mpghighway": "35",
                "mpgcity": "23",
                "categoriesmarket": "Luxury,Performance",
                "epaclass": "Subcompact Cars",
                "vehiclesize": "Compact",
                "crossover": "NA",
                "primarybodytype": "Car"
            }]},
    {
        "id": "BMW_3_Series",
        "name": "3 Series",
        "nicename": "3-series",
        "styles": [
            {
                "id": 200729833,
                "name": "320i 4dr Sedan (2.0L 4cyl Turbo 8A)",
                "drivenwheels": "rear wheel drive",
                "numofdoors": 4,
                "manufacturercode": "16TI",
                "engine": 200741606,
                "transmission": 200741614,
                "trim": "320i",
                "pricebasemsrp": "33150.0",
                "pricebaseinvoice": "31000.0",
                "pricedeliverycharges": "995.0",
                "submodelbody": "Sedan",
                "submodelname": "3 Series Sedan",
                "submodelnicename": "sedan",
                "mpghighway": "36",
                "mpgcity": "24",
                "categoriesmarket": "Luxury",
                "epaclass": "Compact Cars",
                "vehiclesize": "Midsize",
                "crossover": "NA",
                "primarybodytype": "Car"
            }
          ]
       }
  ]
}
 var model = response.model;
 var brandname = response.name;
 $(model).each(function(){
   var series = $(this).get(0);
   $("#view").append("<button id=\""+series.id+"\" name=\""+series.id+"\">"+brandname+" "+series.name+"</button>");
   $(document).on("click","#"+series.id,function() { 
    $(series.styles).each(function(){
    var make = $(this).get(0);
    if($("#"+make.id).length<=0) {
       $("#subview").append("<button id=\""+make.id+"\" name=\""+make.id+"\">"+make.name+"</button>");
    } else {
    $("#"+make.id).remove();
    }
  $(document).on("click","#"+make.id,function() { 
  var carinfo = "";
  for (var prop in make) {
    carinfo += prop+' = '+make[prop]+"\n";
  }
  alert(carinfo);
  });
       });
   });   
   });
```

```css
#view button,#subview button{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  padding:2rem;
}
#view button {
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#326d1a;
}
#subview button{
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#a22fa1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="view"></div>
<div id="subview"></div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed for "state 3", however for State 2, I would like there to be an intermediate buttons that simply states the model.name, i.e. "2 Series", "3 Series", "4 Series," ... and THEN have the snippet you provided to be integrated. Will mark as answered if you can update the code snippet. Thanks a million!

Comment: @Miguel i changed my answer a bit. This way you get separate buttons per series that on click will produce you the associated car buttons.

Comment: Bless. thank you for going the extra mile and more !

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a code snippet like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/makes/' + make_id + '.json', function( models     ) {
       $(models.model).each(function(){
           console.log(this.name + ' ' + this.id)
       });
```